# How to size a SVG icon via a <use> element like an image

Tags: html, css, svg

In my HTML document I have an `<svg>` that includes many items with `id` attributes like `icon-x`.

I then want to reuse these icons like

```html
<div class=container>
  <svg><use xlink:href=#icon-x /></svg>
</div>
```

However, the icons in this case may be different sizes within the source SVG. I want them to fit the `div.container`, but the svg in the container has whitespace around it.

How can I tell it to `<use>` the thing I point to, and know that that thing defines the size of the `<svg>`, so that then when I do CSS like `.container svg { width: 100%; height: auto;}` it works as it would an `<img>` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The `icon-x` must be a symbol or a nested svg with a viewBox attribute
2. When using the `icon-x` you give the `<use>` element an `width` and a `height`.
   You can also give the `<use>` a different position (x and y attributes) or a different fill.

In the next example I'm using a `<symbol>`. You can choose to use a nested svg instead. In this case you may want to put it in a `<defs>`

```css
svg{
border:solid;
width:90vh;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 240 240">
<symbol  id="icon-x"  viewBox="0 0 24 24">
   <path d="M21 16v-2l-8-5v-5.5c0-.83-.67-1.5-1.5-1.5s-1.5.67-1.5 1.5v5.5l-8 5v2l8-2.5v5.5l-2 1.5v1.5l3.5-1 3.5 1v-1.5l-2-1.5v-5.5l8 2.5z"></path>
</symbol>
  <use xlink:href="#icon-x" x="10" y="10" width="150" height="150"/>
  <use xlink:href="#icon-x" x="120" y="120" width="50" height="50" fill="blue"/>
</svg>
```